# How to fix the error in accessing the content of a text file error

Tags: python

I use this code to 0

I use python itertools.permutations to generate a permutations of a certain list of content to a text file as follows

```
    from collections import deque
    import numpy as np
    import math
    import yaml
    import sys
    import pickle
    import ast
    from gym import Env, spaces
    from gym.utils import seeding
    from envs.core_v2 import BS, UE
    from itertools import permutations,product,combinations, compress
    from envs.utils import get_len_space, relaxed_to_one_hot, to_categorical
    sys.getsizeof(float())
     
    with open("reduction.txt", "w") as file:
         no_actions = 0
         UEs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
         List_UE = [list(p) for p in product(*UEs)]
         comb = permutations(List_UE, int(3))
         for i in comb:            
             unique_elements, counts= np.unique(list(i), return_counts=True)
             if all(counts == 1):
                no_actions += 1
                file.write("{},".format(list(i)))
         file.close()
```

When I try to access the content later by the following code

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import math
import yaml
import sys
import pickle
import ast
from gym import Env, spaces
from gym.utils import seeding
from envs.core_v2 import BS, UE
from itertools import permutations,product,combinations, compress
from envs.utils import get_len_space, relaxed_to_one_hot, to_categorical
sys.getsizeof(float())

with open("reduction.txt", 'r') as file:
     content = file.read()
     #content.removesuffix(",")
     action_list = ast.literal_eval(f'[{content}]')
     # print(len(action_list),action_index)
     action = action_list[action_index]
```

I got this error in the access

```
File "/projappl/project_2006417/Journal_MEC_UseCase_26_08_2023/envs/mecsch_v2.py", line 519, in _NOMA_action_set_Red_access
action_list = ast.literal_eval(f'[{content}]')
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ast.py", line 62, in literal_eval
node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, flags
File "<unknown>", line 1
    [[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 19]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 16]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 17]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 12]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 8]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 11]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 7]],[[9, 18], [0, 6], [14, 5]],

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
/usr/lib64/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 5 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

[slurm file for the error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kerZg8OVMWi0VzyD5CuhVS3I_O6RgEhF/view?usp=sharing)
Can you please help fix this error?

Comment: Your error_message is incomplete, please give us the full error message or the last line of it atleast.

Comment: Did you copy the code that writes the file correctly? You're calling `file.close()` during the first iteration, so it should get an error on the second combination. You shouldn't call `file.close()` at all, the context manager will close it automatically when the loop finishes.

Comment: It is after the for loop. I just mistyped it

Comment: @Razzer  I added the lines after it actually lists all the list after

Comment: The Error message is still incomplete some lines are missing.

Comment: @Razzer I attached the slurm file for the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have multiple objects in the file. `ast.literal_eval()` expects the argument to be a single object.

Instead of writing a list each time through the loop, collect everything into a single list and write that at the end.

```
all_actions = []
no_actions = 0
UEs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
List_UE = [list(p) for p in product(*UEs)]
comb = permutations(List_UE, int(3))

for i in comb:            
    unique_elements, counts= np.unique(list(i), return_counts=True)
    if all(counts == 1):
        no_actions += 1
        all_actions.append(list(i)))

with open("reduction.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(all_actions))
```

Comment: the main issue is that I have a large list and I had a run out of memory issue that is way I do it that way and not create a list.

Comment: If you can't fit it all into memory, what are you planning on doing when you try to read it?

Comment: I discussed this issue in this post stackoverflow.com/questions/76943348/… and that is why I store and read it from a text file. What I am thinking of doing is reading the requested line and converting it to a list

Comment: You could put a newline between each item that you write. Then read them one line at a time and call `ast.literal_eval()` to read just that item.